# Spring Kafka with multiple Partition & multiple listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to setup multiple partition for a topic, Let say 3 partition. Also it would have 3 consumers within same group reading from these partition (1-1 mapping as per kafka design).

My configurations are as follows :

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaMessageContainer() throws Exception {
    
    //Setting 3 Partition
    ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 0), new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 1), new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 2));
    //Group id is set same for multiple instances of this service
    containerProps.setGroupId(groupId);
    
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer <String, String>(kafkaConsumerFactory(kafkaBootStrapServers), containerProps);
    
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(KAFKA_RETRY_INTERVAL, KAFKA_RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPT)));
    //Setting 3 listeners
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    
    return factory;
}
private ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory(String kafkaBootStrapServers) {
        
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootStrapServers);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
    
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(config);
}
```

When i run this from single instance of my service then listeners are running fine with reading message from their respective topic-partition (no duplicate). But when i created 2 instance of the service then listener from both the instances are reading from same topic-partition again.
This leads to duplicate processing of same message.

My question is if i didn't change group id of listener in both instances then why listeners in different instance reading same message again. Also how can i ensure it works fine as in single instance.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 0), new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 1), new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 2));`

You are manually assigning the partitions so the `group.id` is irrelevant for assignment purposes.

If you want to distribute the partitions across multiple instances using group management, you need to just use `ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(topic);`.

You will need at least 6 partitions for 2 instances with concurrency = 3; otherwise you will have idle consumers.

When there is only one instance, it will get all 6 partitions.